# Show that there exists a unique solution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, bilinear-form

Help me to understanding the Lax-Milgram Theorem.

I've shown that there exits a bilinear form
$$ a : H_0^1([0,1]) \times H_0^1([0,1]) \to \mathbb{R}, (u,v) \mapsto \int_0^1 ( u'v' - K uv), \quad \text{ where } K \text{ is a constant}
$$
Does this imply by the Lax-Milgram theorem that the differential equation $y'' - Ky = 0$ with boundary conditions $y(0) = y(1) = 0$ has a unique solution?

I know that by the Lax-Milgram theorem there exists a unique $u \in H_0^1([0,1])$ such that for all bounded $f \in H_0^1([0,1])^*$ (linear), we have
$$ a(u,v) = f(v).
$$
Do I have to choose the constant zero function here to conclude?

Comment: you have to show that the bilinear form $a$ is coercive first. Then you can conclude that there exist a unique solution to $a(u,v) = f(v),\ \forall v\in H^1_0$. With the Lax-Milgram theorem you can only say it is a weak solution however. I am not sure what you want to conclude exactly in your second question.

Comment: Ok so Lax-Milgram and the bilinear form a(u,v) is not enough to show that y'' - Ky= 0 has a unique solution?

Comment: No indeed. See the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions%E2%80%93Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem.